# Getting MouseButton event when it happens, not when it is released

Tags: c#, xna, mouseevent, mouseclick-event, registerhotkey

Simply put, I want to be able to get the event of a mouseclick (specifically MiddleButton) when a user clicks the button - not after it's been released.

I think I've done it once before, but I've forgotten.

This is to be able to navigate a 3D view when the user clicks the button, in an XNA project.

Are there any similiar ways to register HotKeys but for the Mouse?

Comment: Can you not use MouseDown instead of MouseClick?

Comment: Is this really an XNA question? Are you using XNA's `Mouse` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't that just the `MouseDown` event?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot all about what they do. Just use to MouseClick... Sorry. It was probably something similiar I thought about but not quite, that required that something is set before hand. I have about 3 layers of controls so it's easy to place it at the wrong control for it to register too.